# How to extract the year, month, day and time into 4 different columns from a single column

Tags: r

I have a data  set consisting a column like

```
Year
1/1/1996 9:00
1/2/1996 9:00
1/3/1996 9:00
1/4/1996 9:00
1/5/1996 9:00
1/6/1996 9:00
1/7/1996 9:00
1/8/1996 9:00
1/9/1996 9:00
1/10/1996 9:00
```

I want to create 4 different columns, which will look something like this

```
Year            Month   Day   Year  Time
1/1/1996 9:00   1       1     1996  9:00
1/2/1996 9:00   1       2     1996  9:00 
1/3/1996 9:00   1       3     1996  9:00 
1/4/1996 9:00   1       4     1996  9:00
1/5/1996 9:00   1       5     1996  9:00
1/6/1996 9:00   1       6     1996  9:00
1/7/1996 9:00   1       7     1996  9:00
1/8/1996 9:00   1       8     1996  9:00
1/9/1996 9:00   1       9     1996  9:00
1/10/1996 9:00  1       10    1996  9:00
```

Is it possible to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate` from `library(tidyr)`.  We specify the new variables to be created in the `into`.  Other arguments include the `sep` to specify the delimiter, `remove` to return the keep the original column or not, and change the column class of the new variables with `type.convert=TRUE`.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, Year, into=c('Month', 'Day', 'Year', 'Time'),
                      sep='[/ ]', remove=FALSE, type.convert=TRUE)
#             Year Month Day Year Time
#1   1/1/1996 9:00     1   1 1996 9:00
#2   1/2/1996 9:00     1   2 1996 9:00
#3   1/3/1996 9:00     1   3 1996 9:00
#4   1/4/1996 9:00     1   4 1996 9:00
#5   1/5/1996 9:00     1   5 1996 9:00
#6   1/6/1996 9:00     1   6 1996 9:00
#7   1/7/1996 9:00     1   7 1996 9:00
#8   1/8/1996 9:00     1   8 1996 9:00
#9   1/9/1996 9:00     1   9 1996 9:00
#10 1/10/1996 9:00     1  10 1996 9:00
```

---

Another option is `tstrsplit` from `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), split the 'Year' column (`tstrsplit(Year, ...)`) and assign the output (`:=`) to create new columns.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, c('Month', 'Day', 'year', 'Time') := tstrsplit(Year, '[/ ]',
                    type.convert=TRUE)]
```

---

Or another option is `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'Year', '[/ ]', fixed=FALSE, drop=FALSE, type.convert=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c("1/1/1996 9:00", "1/2/1996 9:00",
"1/3/1996 9:00", 
"1/4/1996 9:00", "1/5/1996 9:00", "1/6/1996 9:00", "1/7/1996 9:00", 
"1/8/1996 9:00", "1/9/1996 9:00", "1/10/1996 9:00")), .Names = "Year", 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried `separate(df1, Year, into=c('Month', 'Day', 'Year', 'Time'),
                      sep='[/ ]', remove=FALSE, type.convert=TRUE)`. But it is giving an error `Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  : 
  argument is of length zero`

Comment: @ShretaGhimire Are you using the same data in my post?  I am using `tidyr_0.3.1.9000`

Comment: @ShretaGhimire I also updated with a couple of other options.  Check if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. it works perfect for my dataset. Now I can split year in several  huge dataframe that i have.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire  Thanks for the feedback.  Glad to know that it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some packages.

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringi)
df <- read_tsv("Year
            1/1/1996 9:00
            1/2/1996 9:00
            1/3/1996 9:00
            1/4/1996 9:00
            1/5/1996 9:00
            1/6/1996 9:00
            1/7/1996 9:00
            1/8/1996 9:00
            1/9/1996 9:00
            1/10/1996 9:00", 
            col_types = list(Year = col_datetime(format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")))

mutate_each(df, 
            funs(month, day, year, hour, stri_datetime_format(time = Year,     
            format = "HH:mm", tz = "UTC")), 
            Year)
```